# cannot free memory (assertion error)

Tags: c, pointers, free

I'm getting an assertion error (expression: crtisvalidheappointer) when I try to free my circular buffer.  Why is this happening?

Relevant structs:

```
typedef struct quote {
    unsigned int seconds;
    double rate;
} quote;

typedef struct cbuf {
    unsigned int max;
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int end;
    unsigned int size;
    quote *quotes;
} cbuf;
```

Block of code that mallocs and frees:

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE 10
static cbuf cb1 = {INITIAL_SIZE, 0, 0, 0, NULL};
cb1.quotes = (quote*)malloc(INITIAL_SIZE * sizeof(quote));
if(cb1.quotes == NULL)
{
    printf("Error - memory allocation failed.");
    exit(1);
}

free(&cb1);
```

Comment: You're freeing a local stack variable. SideNote: Don't cast `malloc()` when programming in C. Its a bad habit.

Comment: You want to `free(&(cb1.quotes))` since `cb1.quotes` is what you allocated memory for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
free(&cb1);
```

You're trying to free the memory where `cb1` resides, but

```
static cbuf cb1 = {INITIAL_SIZE, 0, 0, 0, NULL};
```

that was not `malloc`ed.

```
free(cb1.quotes)
```

is what you need to free.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot free what you haven't allocated:

```
free(&cb1);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you need to remember is : you can free the memory only which you have dynamically allocated

in your case, you have dynamically allocated memory for "cb1.quotes" not for cb1
so you must free cb1.quotes not the cb1.

with regards

Hims